# PHP Not returning results

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

The following loop is currently not returning any results but when placing an echo just before $timestring is called again it displays the next values. Why would no results be displayed?

The code should return all results between a certain date range, and loop through to the following week each time. For example the first week being from 2015-08-10 to 2015-08-17 then loop and get results for the next week being 2015-08-17 to 2015-08-24.

```php
include 'connect.php';
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$date = date('Y-m-d');

$startdate = '2015-08-10';
$finishdate = '2015-08-17';

$query = "SELECT * FROM poc_report_live";

$mainresults = mysql_query($query);

$timestring = $startdate;
$timestringend = $finishdate;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mainresults)){
    $pulldate = $row['Date'];   
    $pullincident = $row['Incident Type'];  
    //echo $timestring."<br>";  
    if(($pulldate >= $timestring) and ($pulldate <= $timestringend)){
        if ($pullincident == '1'){
            echo $row['Ref']."<br>";
        }
    }

    $timestring = strtotime($timestring);
    $timestring = strtotime("+7 day", $timestring);
    $timestring = date('Y-m-d', $timestring);

    $timestringend = strtotime($timestringend);
    $timestringend = strtotime("+7 day", $timestringend);
    $timestringend = date('Y-m-d', $timestringend); 
    //echo $timestring."<br>";
}
```

Comment: So, what happens if you uncomment those `echo` statements?

Comment: its just prints the dates for as many times as there are entries in the sql db

Comment: So, what's the problem here?  I'm guessing `echo $row['Ref']` is never running?  What format is your `$row['Date']` in?  You may want to run `strtotime()` on `$row['Date']` and `$timestring` before comparing.